# How to hide Data Saver icon in Status bar?

Tags: notification-icons

I've recently enabled the Data Saver feature in Android (Settings). So far so good, but that icon [image] in the Status bar annoys me a lot. I prefer to have only a handful but very specific icons in my Status Bar.

I looked into GravityBox [O] module, All My... module and searched for some more in Xposed modules repository and outside but to no avail.

How do I hide that pesky icon?

I'm using stock and rooted Android 8.1 with Xposed Framework in OnePlus 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SystemUITuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zacharee1.systemuituner&hl=en_US), it is possible to remove to remove the data saver icon with or without root (need to grant permission through adb when the device is not rooted).

1. Open the app, click on `TO THE TWEAKS`.
2. Select `Status bar`. Scroll to the `Networking & Data` section, then disable `Data Saver Icon`.

Note: I performed the steps above on a non-rooted device with Android 8.1.

**Disclaimer:** I am just a user of the app not its developer(s) nor related to him/her/them.